# Is there a way to filter an adapter with multiple types of filters at the same time?

Tags: java, android, listview, filter, android-arrayadapter

I'm trying to filter a list created by an adapter using three different types of filters, but no matter what I do, I can't make the filter respect all three when they are selected simultaneously by the user. If the user only activates one kind of filter, it works fine.

I think its because inside the getFilter method, its filtering three times, but when the second type of filter begins it's not taking into account what the first one did.

How can I filter my list making it respect all three filters?

I tried searching for a way, but these are the closest I could find to my issue:

[How to apply multiple Filters on an Adapter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11390890/how-to-apply-multiple-filters-on-an-adapter)

[Filtering ListView with custom (object) adapter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5780289/filtering-listview-with-custom-object-adapter)

But none of them deal with multiple filters being applied at the same time.

Here's my adapter's code:

```
@Override
    public Filter getFilter() {
        Filter filter = new Filter() {

            @Override
            protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
                FilterResults results = new FilterResults();
                List<Viagem> objects = new ArrayList<Viagem>();

                for (Viagem viagem : Activity.disp.Viagens1) { 
                    if (!filtroHoraMin.equals("")) { //If its range of time filter.
                        if ((Integer.parseInt(viagem.Voos.get(0).HoraSaida.substring(0,2)) >= Integer.parseInt(filtroHoraMin)) &&
                                (Integer.parseInt(viagem.Voos.get(0).HoraSaida.substring(0,2)) <= Integer.parseInt(filtroHoraMax))){
                            objects.add(viagem);
                            continue;
                        }
                    }

                    if (filterArray[9] != ""){ //Second type of filter
                        int paradas = Integer.parseInt(filterArray[9].toString());
                        if (paradas == -1) { //Todas as viagens
                            objects.add(viagem);
                            continue;
                        }
                        int paradasViagem = viagem.Voos.size() - 1;
                        for (Voo voo : viagem.Voos) {
                            paradasViagem += voo.QuantidadeParadas;
                        }
                        if (paradasViagem == paradas) { //Viagens diretas
                            objects.add(viagem);
                            continue;
                        }
                    }

                    if(constraint == "cias") {
                        if(filterArray[0] == "All"){
                            objects.add(viagem);
                        }
                        else {
                            for (int i=1; i<9; i++){
                                if (filterArray[i]!= ""){
                                    if (viagem.Cia.equals(filterArray[i])) {
                                        objects.add(viagem);
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                results.values = objects;
                results.count = objects.size();
                return results;
            }

            @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
            @Override
            protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results) {
                viagens = (List<Viagem>) results.values;
                if (results.count > 0) {
                    notifyDataSetChanged();
                } else {
                    notifyDataSetInvalidated();
                }
            }

        };
        return filter;
    }
}
```

In this case, as the getFilter only accepts one constraint and I need to be able to check multiple, I created an array of filters and check each of them if they are not empty and apply the operation.

**filterArray[9] is the position of the second type of filter.**

**filterArray 0 to 8 contains the companies** that can be selected for filtering.

And here's the method called when the user presses the Apply Filters Button:

```
public void ApplyFilters(){
    viagensArrayAdapter.getFilter().filter("cias");

    Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), "Success!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

Comment: There is such pattern which is called `Composition`. You can write `CompositeFilter` which just goes over other filters.

Comment: You mean like this https://github.com/smalldatalab/android-context/blob/master/funf-library/src/main/java/edu/mit/media/funf/filter/CompositeFilter.java ?

The problem there is that it uses a Datasource. I want to filter a list that was previously acquired from a webservice (not search again).

Comment: Oh, I didn't knew it existed. It doesn't matter that it uses DataSources - as you can see it's fairly simple, so you can write your own version which takes several `Filter` objects instead